# Count movie play on website using google analytics

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-analytics

I have some movies on my website. Can I somehow use Google Analytics to count how many times concrete movie was played? I am completely new in GA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Google Analytics Event tracking to do that.  In fact GA's example documentation has an example on using event tracking to track the playing of movies [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide#Anatomy):

There is a newer version of the Google Analytics library termed "Universal Analytics" which you should use.  [Universal analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events) uses "analytics.js", but the concept of event tracking in GA, using category, action, label, value is the same.

Comment: So I have to create an account, insert ga.js and... that's all?

Comment: I've updated my answer.  All you need is an account and now analytics.js